# SSH ClientAlive configuration not applying to SCP/SFTP connections

Tags: ssh, rhel, sshd

Under /etc/ssh/sshd_config I have:

```
ClientAliveInterval 900
ClientAliveCountMax 0
```

Which essentially closes a SSH session after 15 minutes. This works as expected when connecting to the server using Putty or other tools to initialize SSH sessions. But when using SFTP or SCP (using port 22), those sessions stay active indefinitely. Since they use `sshd`, wouldn't the same configuration for terminal sessions apply?

Using RHEL 6.10.

EDIT: Fixed incorrect setting name.

Comment: Are there active data transfers when you expect them to time out in 15 minutes?

Comment: Nope, just sitting there. I've had the same SFTP session established for 2 days doing nothing.

Comment: Assuming you meant to say `ClientAliveCountMax`, setting it to zero disables terminations due to timeout. https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ClientAliveCountMax

Comment: Is suspect your client is sending a ServerAlive packet and resetting the counter.

Comment: Those two settings are based on these STIGs: RHEL-06-000230 and RHEL-06-000231. Looking at the man pages for sshd_config in the server, ClientAliveInterval 0 would disable the whole mechanism, but by doing ClientAliveInterval 900 and ClientAliveCountMax, one message after 15 minutes of inactivity disconnect the session. 

For SCP I am using winscp.exe and for SFTP I am using psftp.exe, do these send keep alive packets by default?

Comment: Sorry I’m not familiar with Windows software.

Answer (score 1):

You have two issues here.  One, as mentioned in the comments, is that `ClientAliveCountMax` set to 0 disables the keepalive mechanism, at least in OpenSSH 8.2.  You need to set it to a positive value in order for OpenSSH to send keepalives at all.  3 is usually a suitable value.

The other is that these settings do not disconnect *all* idle connections, but only idle connections where *the client is not reachable*.  In other words, they are there for the case of detecting when a client goes away.  Moreover, sending keepalives will keep the TCP connection alive indefinitely provided both the server and client maintain suitable network connections.

For example, I can turn on these settings for one server and mount a disk on that server using SFTP on another machine, and as long as they maintain a reliable network connection, the SFTP connection will persist.

Comment: I do not see how this could explain the questioners observation of the difference between SSH and SFTP.

Comment: Probably something is sent through the shell is causing a packet to be sent and not acknowledged, causing the TCP connection to reset.  SFTP isn't sending packets if there's no data.